# Unable to deploy community: no Network named MySItes

Tags: deployment, error, experience-cloud, network

When I am trying to deploy my experience cloud site to clean scratch org I get following errors:

```
Error    sdx_sourceDeploy_pkg_1627387377741/networkBranding/cbMySites.networkBranding          cbMySites           Network not found for the CustomBrand : cbMySites
Error    sdx_sourceDeploy_pkg_1627387377741/navigationMenus/Default_Navigation.navigationMenu  Default_Navigation  In field: Network - no Network named MySites found
Error    sdx_sourceDeploy_pkg_1627387377741/navigationMenus/Navigation_Bar.navigationMenu      Navigation_Bar      In field: Network - no Network named MySites found
Error    sdx_sourceDeploy_pkg_1627387377741/networks/MySites.network                           MySites             In field: PicassoSite - no SiteDotCom named MySites1 found
Error    sdx_sourceDeploy_pkg_1627387377741/experiences/MySites1                              MySites1             In field: Network - no Network named MySites found
```

Additionally `project-scratch-def.json` looks like following:

```json
{
    "orgName": "scratch-org",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": [
        "EnableSetPasswordInApi",
        "DebugApex",
        "Communities",
        "PublishExpBuilderBasedSna",
        "PublishAuraExpBuilderBasedSna"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "mobileSettings": {
            "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
        },
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true
        },
        "experienceBundleSettings": {
            "enableExperienceBundleMetadata": true
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment of package.xml

```xml
    <types>
        <members>MySites</members>
        <name>Network</name>
    </types>
```

I wonder why Network is not found because is present in package.xml and project source folder.

Comment: what else is set in your `scratch-def.json`?

Comment: did you create community with same name & template in scratch org before deploying your community metadata?

Comment: Is it neccessary to create community on the target scratch org?

Comment: yes, you need to create community before deploying your community metadata using sfdx force:community:create --name "My Customer Community" --templatename "Customer Service" --urlpathprefix customers --description "My customer community

Comment: Step that You mentioned @sdandamud1 - creation community before deploying is prerequisite also when I deploy to production org, sandbox or developer edition org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deploying community in to scratch org is not straight way like other salesforce apps.

**here are the steps i used in my script:**

-- **Create Scratch org/ orgshape is best suite if you have since it pulls all partener licenses**

1. sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a testcommunitySO

-- **create community in scratch org(community Name should source community Name)**

2. sfdx force:community:create --name "source community name" --templatename "source community template Name" --urlpathprefix sourcecommunityurlprefix --description "test community"

-- **deploy org Metadata include All (Apexclass,LWC,Aura,Layouts,Flow,CustomObject
e.t.c) except Community metadata like (ApexPage,CustomSite,ExperienceBundle,NavigationMenu,Network,Profile)**

3. sfdx force:source:deploy -m ApexClass,Layout,CustomObject,LightningComponentBundle,ManagedContentType,CustomObject,StaticResource,CustomTab,PermissionSet,Flow

-- **deploy experience site Metadata include All (ApexPage,CustomSite,ExperienceBundle,NavigationMenu,Network,Profile)**

4. sfdx force:source:deploy -m ApexPage,CustomSite,ExperienceBundle,NavigationMenu,Network,Profile

-- **publish the community**

sfdx force:community:publish -n "mycommunityName"

Comment: Creation of community before actual deployment looks for me like fixing a bug. Is there official documentation that describes that in detail - why is it prerequisite for successful community deployment?

Comment: there is no official document to deploy community in to scratch org, i prepared script from different blog posts, but this one helps me lot https://github.com/trailheadapps/az-insurance