# Deploying Experience site fails due to 'The value for urlPathPrefix in ExperienceBundle isn't valid. Check the value and try again.' with VS Code

Tags: community, deployment, experience-cloud

when trying to deploy experience site with vs code via azure DevOps I'm receiving the following error message: The value for urlPathPrefix in ExperienceBundle isn't valid. Check the value and try again.
There are no static resources or images in the deployment.
What can be the issue?

Comment: welcome to SFSE,  did you create community with same name in target org?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I didn't open a community in target org. I want to deploy a new community site without any manual steps. all other deployments are successful expect this error

Comment: are you deploying your community 1st time? if yes 1st time community deployment is not a straight forward. like other apps. you have to do some pre deployment steps other wise your community deployment won't success. to pre deployment steps you can build your own script if you want avoid manually. for reference please check my previous answer. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/350641/unable-to-deploy-community-no-network-named-mysites/350652#350652

Comment: Was anyone able to get this fixed? We are also getting same issue.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in the `<urlPathPrefix>newValue</urlPathPrefix>`

This happens when you have changed the url of the ExperienceBundle. Let's say initially the url was oldValue but then you change it to newValue.

When you pull the metadata .network it pulls the new urlPathPrefix but you cannot deploy the network unless you change it to the oldValue.

ExperienceBundle, pulls the  `<urlPathPrefix>oldValue/s</urlPathPrefix>` but I could not deploy with changing to newValue/s

There is a known issue: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000mNTrwAAG/siteurlpathprefix-of-chatternetworkpicasso-is-not-getting-updated-when-we-change-the-url-path-of-aura-experience-site

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because in your `<sitename>.site-meta.xml` file found under **experiences** folder you will need to add  urlPathPrefix in a valid format like `<urlPathPrefix>/s</urlPathPrefix>`

Comment: Facing the same issue and have "urlPathPrefix" in xml file. SS: https://ibb.co/dLszyz4 @mohit

Comment: Try adding another prefix like may be /s/mysite

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava, I am facing the same issue. Even after adding above value, facing the same error. Do you have any other solution in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I am embellishing on the earlier answers which helped me solve the same problem.

I had this same problem but the answers did not make sense to me because I did not believe that I had changed the URL.

For example, the Sandbox Digital Experience had a path name. The path name in my URL was 'Prototype'. I did this but it was a long time ago.

[image: Administration Settings for Digital Experience]

To edit the path name you can click on the pencil. The above screenshot shows the pencil. The below screenshot shows the edit screen.

[image: Edit URL Path Name in Digital Experience]

When I created my Digital Experience in Production with the same name - Prototype - I did not fill in the URL Path because it is not required and I had forgotten that I had done this in the Sandbox! So I never changed anything but my URL Paths did not match.

Once I added the 'Prototype' path name to both URLs, they had the same name and I was able to successfully move all my development from Sandbox to Production.

**Before: Error**

Sandbox -  Https://org--test.sandbox.my.site.com/prototype

Production - Https://org.my.site.com

**After: No Error**

Sandbox  - Https://org--test.sandbox.my.site.com/prototype

Production - Https://org.my.site.com/prototype

Thanks for the above clues.